A weaker version of the De Morgan algebras
A De Morgan algebra is a structure  $\langle A, \lor, \land,0,1,\neg \rangle$ such that $\langle A, \lor, \land,0,1 \rangle$ is a bounded distributive lattice and $\neg$ is a  involution that satisfies De Morgan's laws. In a De Morgan algebra the law of the excluded middle $x \lor \neg x \,=\, 1 $ and the law of noncontradiction $x \land \neg x \,=\, 0$ don't have to hold.
My question: is there a similar algebra with the exception that the De Morgan laws don't have to hold?
For instance, a Heyting algebra is similar to what I want since the De Morgan laws do not necessarily hold, however, the law of noncontradiction holds.

There are many such generalizations. What laws specifically would you want it to satisfy (of course some sets of laws entail others which you might want to exclude, but we still need to know what you'd like to preserve or exclude).

@amrsa the laws I want to excluded are the law of the excluded middle and the law of noncontradiction. (so it is similar to the De Morgan algebra except I don't want necessarily to preserve the Morgan laws)

If you just want to exclude those two, with no other restraints, then it's very easy: pick any bounded lattice you want (it can be a Boolean algebra), and append it a new bottom, $\bot$, and a new top element, $\top$, make $\neg\top=\bot$ and $\neg\bot=\top$ all other things being equal. If you want some further restrains then I (or someone else) might find one such example (or show it doesn't exist, depending on the required conditions).

I see I was just wondering if such algebra had a particular name. But I guess the restraints are not many.

Usually, a particular kind of algebra is given a particular name if it becomes interesting (or maybe it just gets a name in a very specific context if it's interesting in that context; this means that if you have a context in which they are interesting, then you can call them whatever in think it's adequate, and maybe very few people will ever notice). Generalizations of Boolean algebras have been given names in many cases because they were interesting (for example, in nonclassical logics).
